# capistrano permission denied error on cap:setup

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, deployment, capistrano, setup-deployment, unicorn

Im trying to deploy a simple application with capistrano nginx and unicorn

- /srv/paintings.git ( initiated and pushed repo )
- /srv/paintings ( place where app should be installed )

**My deploy.rb looks like**

```
  # config/deploy.rb 
require "bundler/capistrano"

set :scm,             :git
set :repository,      "git@109.0.0.0.05:srv/paintings.git"
set :branch,          "origin/master"
set :migrate_target,  :current
set :ssh_options,     { :forward_agent => true }
set :rails_env,       "production"
set :deploy_to,       "/srv/paintings"
set :normalize_asset_timestamps, false

set :user,            "root"
set :group,           "rvm"
set :use_sudo,        true

role :web,    "109.0.0.0.05"
role :app,    "109.0.0.0.05"
role :db,     "109.0.0.0.05", :primary => true

set(:latest_release)  { fetch(:current_path) }
set(:release_path)    { fetch(:current_path) }
set(:current_release) { fetch(:current_path) }

set(:current_revision)  { capture("cd #{current_path}; git rev-parse --short HEAD").strip }
set(:latest_revision)   { capture("cd #{current_path}; git rev-parse --short HEAD").strip }
set(:previous_revision) { capture("cd #{current_path}; git rev-parse --short HEAD@{1}").strip }

default_environment["RAILS_ENV"] = 'production'
default_run_options[:shell] = 'bash'

namespace :deploy do
  desc "Deploy your application"
  task :default do
    update
    restart
  end

  desc "Setup your git-based deployment app"
  task :setup, :except => { :no_release => true } do
    dirs = [deploy_to, shared_path]
    dirs += shared_children.map { |d| File.join(shared_path, d) }
    run "#{try_sudo} mkdir -p #{dirs.join(' ')} && #{try_sudo} chmod g+w #{dirs.join(' ')}"
    run "git clone #{repository} #{current_path}"
  end

  task :cold do
    update
    migrate
  end

  task :update do
    transaction do
      update_code
    end
  end

  desc "Update the deployed code."
  task :update_code, :except => { :no_release => true } do
    run "cd #{current_path}; git fetch origin; git reset --hard #{branch}"
    finalize_update
  end

  desc "Update the database (overwritten to avoid symlink)"
  task :migrations do
    transaction do
      update_code
    end
    migrate
    restart
  end

  task :finalize_update, :except => { :no_release => true } do
    run "chmod -R g+w #{latest_release}" if fetch(:group_writable, true)

    # mkdir -p is making sure that the directories are there for some SCM's that don't
    # save empty folders
    run <<-CMD
      rm -rf #{latest_release}/log #{latest_release}/public/system #{latest_release}/tmp/pids &&
      mkdir -p #{latest_release}/public &&
      mkdir -p #{latest_release}/tmp &&
      ln -s #{shared_path}/log #{latest_release}/log &&
      ln -s #{shared_path}/system #{latest_release}/public/system &&
      ln -s #{shared_path}/pids #{latest_release}/tmp/pids &&
      ln -sf #{shared_path}/database.yml #{latest_release}/config/database.yml
    CMD

    if fetch(:normalize_asset_timestamps, true)
      stamp = Time.now.utc.strftime("%Y%m%d%H%M.%S")
      asset_paths = fetch(:public_children, %w(images stylesheets javascripts)).map { |p| "#{latest_release}/public/#{p}" }.join(" ")
      run "find #{asset_paths} -exec touch -t #{stamp} {} ';'; true", :env => { "TZ" => "UTC" }
    end
  end

  desc "Zero-downtime restart of Unicorn"
  task :restart, :except => { :no_release => true } do
    run "kill -s USR2 `cat /tmp/unicorn.my_site.pid`"
  end

  desc "Start unicorn"
  task :start, :except => { :no_release => true } do
    run "cd #{current_path} ; bundle exec unicorn_rails -c config/unicorn.rb -D"
  end

  desc "Stop unicorn"
  task :stop, :except => { :no_release => true } do
    run "kill -s QUIT `cat /tmp/unicorn.my_site.pid`"
  end  

  namespace :rollback do
    desc "Moves the repo back to the previous version of HEAD"
    task :repo, :except => { :no_release => true } do
      set :branch, "HEAD@{1}"
      deploy.default
    end

    desc "Rewrite reflog so HEAD@{1} will continue to point to at the next previous release."
    task :cleanup, :except => { :no_release => true } do
      run "cd #{current_path}; git reflog delete --rewrite HEAD@{1}; git reflog delete --rewrite HEAD@{1}"
    end

    desc "Rolls back to the previously deployed version."
    task :default do
      rollback.repo
      rollback.cleanup
    end
  end
end

def run_rake(cmd)
  run "cd #{current_path}; #{rake} #{cmd}"
end
```

**Log output:**
**when doing a cap:setup**

```
       [109.etc] env RAILS_ENV=production sh -c 'git clone git@109.etc:srv/paintings.git /srv/paintings/current'
 ** [out :: 109.etc] Initialized empty Git repository in /srv/paintings/current/.git/
 ** [out :: 109.etc] The authenticity of host '109.etc (109.etc)' can't be established.
 ** [out :: 109.etc] RSA key fingerprint is e9:af etc.
 ** [out :: 109.etc] Are you sure you want to continue connecting (yes/no)?

Typing Yes keeps me waiting forever with no status updates
```

Comment: Check whether the releases[/srv/paintings/releases] folder is present in your production machine. I think you have to create this folder manually in production machine.

Comment: thx. it wasn't present, tried to add it manually but the error persisted

Comment: set :use_sudo as false and try it.

Comment: Thx already tried that too before, didn't worked. have no idea hot to fix this its still pending

Comment: Yes latest RVM, latest ruby and latest rails

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I got a similar error once when I told Capistrano to connect to a ssh server which I have never before connected to. Have you tried connecting to the sever (with the same user, ie. `root` and not `git`) simply with `ssh root@109.0.0.0.05`?

It'll probably ask you again if you want to trust the server. If that is the case, my guess is that Capistrano does not react to your 'yes' input.

Also, you connect to your server as root. That means you should not need to have `use_sudo` set to `true`.

Comment: Got this fixed, thx haven't been able to update the post. It seems deploy now all runs but have some small issues with it like unicorn but guess that won't fit in this bounty.

Comment: Not fully yet I'm horrible stuck again on another part and think of posting a question on that but that will be in another topic. thx

Answer (score 1):

do not use `default_environment["PATH"]         = "--"` or provide a full path to `bash` somehow (usually `/bin/bash`)

Comment: Thx for pointing out something so obvious , i *totally* missed that even though I've looked at it several times, not good enough so it seems. Changed that section as in update posted. But the problem exact the same persists